# Protecting Froms From Scriptable Spamming

Tags: php, javascript, forms, spam-prevention

So I have a form that can create an account and right now the process to create the account is by calling a javascript REST API.  I was thinking that it might be really easy to hack that programmatically since all they would need to do it look at the javascript to find out the url to spam and that it might be safer to do the processing in a PHP script.  Then I though well, they could just look at the form to find the URL just as easy if I don't do it through javascript.  The form is going to be processing only POST data but not sure if that is enough and if it matters if i process it through javascript or PHP.

What it the best way to prevent someone from spamming a form programmatically (ie prevent them from writing server, like PHP, or client, like javascript, code to spams the processing script).

Comment: For your form to work in the first place, the client needs to have all the information it needs to submit the form.  Therefore, there's nothing you can do to prevent someone from obtaining this information and using it in a script.  The best you can do is some sort of human recognition strategy, like Captcha as kjy112 suggested.

Comment: this is assumed you have all the client and server side validations in place for the required fields already, obviously.  there are other new 'captcha' coming out that requires user to watch a video but i think that's a bit too much for what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use Captcha to filter the bots out [reCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) but its not 100% protection

Answer (score 1):

Using Captcha is probably the first method:
[Google's Version](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)

Secondly I would do data checking on the server side and possibly email verification, if the E-Mail is not verified I would have a cron to clean out the rows in your table which don't have e-mail verification.

With these two methods you should avoid a good majority of it.

Answer (score 1):

Go for [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha). It's pretty easy.

You can obtain a key pair there by registering your website URL. Use that key to generate the reCAPTCHA image/textbox in your form. Your form's data will be posted and added to database only if entry matches the text displayed in the image, otherwise not (that's aserverside check that you have to keep). You'll get plenty of related code in Google :)

Another technique, as most of the websites now a days follow, is to send an account activation link to the user via email. An account will get created only when that activation link is clicked upon. You can also set an expiration time (say, 24 hours) for this purpose.

Hope this helps.